# How does LaTeX compile packages?

Tags: packages, compiling

I wonder how does the compile process work with LaTeX?

If I am defining `\usepackage{PACKAGENAME}`, and then using a specific command from this package in my LaTeX-file, how does it work?

I thought it compiles Top->Down, or does the compiler exclude the packages in the first place and check it later on if a command is found in the file?

Comment: \usepackage is just `\input` (after a bit of checking about options and things) it inputs the code which is executed just as if it had been in the preamble at that point.

Comment: So EVERY command in this package is been executed? So if i am using just one command of a very large package, it "inputs" all of the package anyway?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how it works.

Comment: unless the package itself defines an option to skip parts of it (some do, most dont)

Comment: @nextrufus Yes, that's what happens: TeX stores all macro definitions made in the package for using them when requested to.

Comment: It's not JUST \input, its \makeatletter\input\makeatother ;-)

Comment: You can pre-compile a _format_ which has your "standard" preample.